# Optimizing compiler removes bug

Tags: c++, xcode, debugging, optimization, compiler-construction

So a lot of people have posted on stack overflow about how compiler optimizations introduce bugs into their program. However, I'm having the opposite problem. I'm writing a C++ program and I have a bug that seems like undefined behavior that only shows up when I set XCode's compiler to off (None[-O0]). If I set it to "fastest, aggressive optimizations [-Ofast]", then the bug disappears.

So I was wondering if anyone has any experience with optimization getting rid of a bug (instead of the more common case of optimization introducing bugs). What are some common causes of this? I'm kind of at a loss of what to do or where to check.

Comment: In only very rare case a compiler introduce bugs with optimization, most of the time that was due to bad programming practice. You have to look into what an optimizer would do, like re-ordering, code elimination, reuse of stack space, register allocation, etc.TL;DR: you need to check the compiled output to see the difference.

Comment: I'd guess memory issues, like uninitialised variables/pointers. As a start, I'd run it through valgrind to try to shake out anything simple.

Comment: The optimization level does not *introduce* or *remove* bugs, the bugs are present in the program, they may just become apparent or be hidden. You are on the lucky side, since you can reproduce the bug in a debug build, just find it and fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Optimization can change evaluation order of expressions, so if your bug is the result, for example, of a specified evaluation order of `foo()` and `bar()` in:

```
 some_function(foo(), bar());
```

then different optimization settings will expose the bug while other ones will hide it.

There are lots of other possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Enabling optimizations can cause freed stack/heap memory to contain valid data for a longer period of time than in a debug build. Some compilers even scrub freed stack/heap memory in debug builds, meaning that freed data is immediately invalid.